# Ajax jQuery post troubles

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble with a bit of code that uses the ajax $.post function to send a name to a php file which then does some stuff with it. I believe the issue to be in the ajax code, because I have found that the posted value never makes it to the $_POST array (i.e. the $_POST array is not set). However, I do not think that there are any syntactical mistakes on either end, so I am confused as to why it does not work.

Here's the jQuery.

```
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('shootNames')) {
                var shootName = $(e.target).attr('id'); 
                var par = $('#' + shootName).parent().attr("id"); 

                $.post("displayImages.php", {shoot: shootName}); //the information I would like to send

                $('#' + par).load("displayImages.php").off('click', $('#' + par));
            }//end if hasClass
```

And the relevant bit of php.

```
if (isset($_POST['shoot'])) {
$shootname = $_POST['shoot'][0]; //pick out just the first member of the $_POST array 
$filepath = "images/u/$foo/$shootname";
$f->FilesAsImages($filepath);
}//end if
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you check the ajax request using your browsers developer tools... there you should be able to see what are the params that are sent to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting `displayImages.php` once in your `$.post` call and there it should return your image, but you don't have a `success` handler in there, so it does nothing with the result. You're then hitting `displayImages.php` again with `.load` and not passing it anything, so it does nothing as expected. Adding a `success` handler to your `$.post` call and doing the work in there, will do what you want.

See the `$.post` documentation for more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Sample code:

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('shootNames')) {
    var shootName = $(e.target).attr('id');
    var par = $('#' + shootName).parent().attr("id");

    $.post("displayImages.php", {
        shoot: shootName
    }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        // this is the success function and the 3 arguments it gives you, remove the 2nd/3rd if you don't use them
        $('#' + par).html(data).off('click', $('#' + par)); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: hey, so I just tried it, like so:

    $.post("displayImages.php", {shoot: shootName}, function () {
      $('#' + par).load("displayImages.php").off('click', $('#' + par));
     });

And it still gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try change from this

```
 $.post("displayImages.php", {shoot: shootName}); //the information I would like to send
```

to this

```
 $.post("displayImages.php", {'shoot[]': shootName}); //the information I would like to send
```

Source :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/